# TabBar and AppBar conflicting

Tags: flutter, dart

So im trying to decrease the size of the appBar, i used  the appbar because i followed a tutorial to implement a TabBar and it used AppBar.. I feel like both of their sizes are conflicting

image reference: [image]

as you can see there is some space below the tabbar and i dont want that to appear...
below is my code

```
child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 48,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              flexibleSpace: TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Venue',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Map',
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [Venue(), Map()],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner but here is my code for TabbedBar. I implemented a transparent appbar, so you could remove that if need be. I could go into more details if needed, and other folks might have better suggestions and probably even correct something from my snippet.

On a separate note, how did you get the routing on your bottom navigation to work? or please provide me with the link tp tutorial you followed

```
child: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: new SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(child: new Container()),
              new TabBar(
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                indicatorWeight: 02.0,
                unselectedLabelStyle:
                TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: [
                  new Text("KINGS",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  new Text("QUEENS",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  new Text("HEIRS",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
   body: new TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[

        new PageView(

          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            Image.asset('images/man1.png', fit: BoxFit.cover
            ),
            Image.asset('images/man5.png', fit: BoxFit.cover
            ),
          ],
        ),       
       );
```

Comment: Sorry.. i just saw ur comment, in the Scaffold widget, u have the ```bottomNavigationBar```, u can use that for the bottom navbar, sorry i dont remember where i got the idea from.. cant send u the link